# C# Transactions - best performance

Tags: c#, performance, transactions

My webapplication has a class `WorkItem` with a `RecordID` (Guid as Primary Key) and a `FriendlyID` (string) that consists of `Type-Date-RandomNumbers`.

If I create a new WorkItem, I create a new FriendlyID as well.
The format of the FriendlyID **cannot be changed** (client specification) and is like `<Type (one char)>-<Current Date (yyymmdd)>-<6 random numbers>`.

```
private string GenerateFriendlyID()
{
    string res = String.Empty;
    // code omited
    // ...
    // IT'S NOT THE QUESTION HOW TO PROGRAM THIS METHOD!
    // It's about the fastest and best way/design to make 
    // sure the generated ID is unique! (see below)
    return res; // sth like "K-20110930-158349"
}

public override void Create()
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(friendlyID))
    {
        GenerateFriendlyID();
    }
    base.Create();
}
```

This code does fails under heavy load, so I get the same FriendlyIDs multiple times.
**What is the best way to make sure that my friendly ID is unique?**

1. Make a UNIQUE-Constraint on FriendlyID in the DB.

   - Begin a transaction, generate a FriendlyID, insert and commit
   - Rollback and try again if I get a SQLException.
2. Just create it.

   - Select all WorkItems with `this.FriendlyID`.
   - If selection is `> 1`, repeat until it's `== 1`

I'm sure there is another way, but **I guess #1** should be the preferred.

Are there any ways I'm missing or is #1 the way to go? I hate to use Exceptions for my workflow though and I know that they're really slow.

Comment: Whhat are the requirements for an ID to be "friendly'?

Comment: Why you can not use `RecordID` as `FriendlyID` are any requirements for the `FriendlyID`?

Comment: Why do you have two column to identify a row in the table? You should only have one. Another thing is, you shouldn't use GUID as clustered index (I'm assuming you're using the default from mssql, the PK)

Comment: I can not understand why the question title contains `best performance`

Comment: The question is not how to generate the FriendlyID, it's about the best and fastest way to make sure it is **unique** and generate a new one if it's not.

Comment: @Jeremy McGee : If I'm not sure - I'm not edit ;) So basically I asking before edit if I'm not sure

Comment: @BrunoCosta client's specification

Comment: Well, in your situation I'll ask the client how he wants to get a friendly ID as string and guaranteed to be unique with good performance. How about if you separate that in 2 columns (Column1:Type + Date; Column2:Number(Identity)? And show them as friendlyID with concat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is in any case, whatever kind of id you want to generate, do this in the SQL in a stored procedure and not from .NET client code. It is always better to have an atomic entry point which takes some parameters and does the job, so you can call the stored and get your record saved and the id back to you as out parameter, even more than one, like a unique code and a guid.

in this way, then, you move concurrency issues from the .NET client code to the Database Server and db servers are **designed** to handle concurrency well.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with our current architecture, but I could create trigger which is called after insert and basically does the same. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: please don't! avoid this kind of sparse logic, just have proper unique index and PK constraint and do everything in the stored proc. Requires some effort but pays off really... I saw so many triggers around for nothing, like setting a default value or doing other things which could and should be done by normal defaults constraints...

Answer (score 2):

As your `RecordID` is already based on a GUID, I'd parse that to create the friendly ID. `Guid.ToByteArray()` may be a useful place to start.

Comment: The question is not about creating the ID, it's about making sure it's unique

Comment: My point /entirely/. GUIDs are /guaranteed/ to be unique. All other (credible) approaches run at the client-side will involve locks and hence potential contention; this might be insurmountable if you run this code from e.g. a farm of Web servers with no interprocess communication. @Davide's proposal to move the generator to the database server will mitigate the performance hit as there is then only one place the IDs are generated, but it won't avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Use the KeyGenerator pattern from PoEAA by M.Fowler. Here is a sample for a file system solution and it uses a mutex for cross process locking. In a case of MS SQL you can use a transaction instead of mutex.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class KeyGenerator
    {
        private string FileName;
        private long IncrementedBy;
        private long NextId;
        private long MaxId; 

        public KeyGenerator(string filename, long incrementedby)
        {
            FileName = filename;
            IncrementedBy = incrementedby;
            NextId = MaxId = 0; 
        }


        //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public long NextID()
        {


            if (NextId == MaxId)
            {
                reserveIds();
            }

            return NextId++; 

        }

        private void reserveIds()
        {

            Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "Mutex " + FileName.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '_'));
            try
            {
                m.WaitOne();
                string s = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
                long newNextId = long.Parse(s);
                long newMaxId = newNextId + IncrementedBy; 
                File.WriteAllText(FileName, newMaxId.ToString());
                NextId = newNextId;
                MaxId = newMaxId;
                // Simulate some work.
                Thread.Sleep(500);

            }
            finally
            {
                m.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }

    }

}
```